# c# pinvoke marshall struct

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke

I have an unmanaged struct I'd like to marshal to c# that looks basically like this:

```
struct DateTimeStruct{
   double datetimestamp;
};   

struct MyStruct{
   char firstname[40];
   char lastname[40];
   DateTimeStruct bday;
   unsigned integer bool1;
   int val1;
};
```

What is the the correct c# declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct isn't a problem, it will marshal correctly as-is.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    struct MyStruct{
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40]
        string firstname;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40]
        string lastname;
        DateTimeStruct bday;
        uint bool1;
        int val1;
    }
```

Of course, it will be up to you to convert the double to a matching DateTime value.  How it is encoded is unguessable from your question.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I created the c structs from a document that describes the dll and have no idea how the DateTimeStruct looks other than this line in a table in the MyStruct documentation: 

Element: Birthday
Type: DateTimeStruct (Double)

Comment: I know C well, "DateTimeStruct(Double)" is not valid C.  How do you know that what you've got isn't actually correct?  Contact the vendor if you want to be sure.

Comment: Thanks I will have to follow up. My c knowledge is dangerous.